# How do you bring back items in Eclipse SVN View when you did 'Remove from view' them?

Tags: eclipse, svn, conflict, svnkit

I hid some files of a SVN repo by using the 'Remove from view' option. It's stated that they would show again in case of modification.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/od4sA.jpg

But now, Eclipse shows conflicts in my project, with absolutely 0 files with conflict.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXufD.jpg

I'm thinking that it might be one of those files, but I can't find any way to show them again. So:

1. Is there a way to reset the repo view in Eclipse?
2. Is there another way to see where the conflict stated by Eclipse is coming from? When I use the svn command line, I don't see any conflict..

Comment: Did my answer help you in 2014? Please, upvote it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Eclipse doc](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/teamSupport/workspace_synch.php) the file should reappear in the View if its conflicted:

> **Remove from View** - removes the selected resource from the view. It
>   will reappear in the view if it's synchronization status changes.

File being in conflict should be considered as "synchronization status change", so I think that the removed-from-view file is not the conflicted one. I guess that you have a tree conflict in your working copy.

To determine the conflicted item, run the following command-line against your working copy:

[`svn status -q`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html)

The output of the command will show conflicted items only.